# function is fired without calling it

Tags: javascript

That's my code when I run it the `openFiles` function (that needs to be fired only after checkbox is clicked) fires anyway and `that` obj is the window not the checkbox... why ? how to fix that? what am I missing?

```
function openFiles(that) {
    alert("have not touched js for a long time :(");
} 

 function checkbox (){          
     var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
     checkbox.type = "checkbox";
     checkbox.name = "chkbox";
     checkbox.id = "chkid" ;
     checkbox.style = "width:50px";
     checkbox.onclick = openFiles(this);                     
}
```

Comment: In your code, `onclick` doesn't receive a function, but the value returned by the execution of `openFiles(this)` (which is `undefined` in this specific example).

Comment: `checkbox.onclick = () => openFiles(this);`

Comment: Where are you calling openFile() function ??

Comment: You need to bind the checkbox not `this`. `checkbox.onclick =  openFiles.bind(checkbox)` so you are able to get the checkbox with `this`. Now you can use it `alert(this)`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks!  but 'this' obj is still the window and not the checkbox

Comment: Use `checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) { openFiles(this); })` instead

Comment: @Ifaruki thanks just what I was looking for